# How to Run e2e tests on multiple browsers in series?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, browsers, protractor

I am running e2e tests using Protractor on a VM through azure.  I want to run tests on multiple browsers, which Protractor allows me to do by adding a list like this (from the protractor.config file):

```
multiCapabilities: [
   {'browserName': 'internet explorer'},
   {'browserName': 'chrome'}
]
```

And I can add more browsers to that list.  However, when protractor launches it runs both browsers in parallel, which is great for saving time but I believe it is too much for this VM to handle and is causing some tests to timeout.  How can I tell protractor to run the test on each browser I specify in series rather than parallel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
multiCapabilities: [
  {'browserName': 'internet explorer'},
  {'browserName': 'chrome'}
],

maxSessions: 1,
```

Comment: what does this do?

Comment: @TESTasy [MaxSession This says....how many browsers (Any Browser and any version) can run in parallel at a time in the remote system. So this overrides the Max Instances settings and can restrict the number of browser instances that can run in parallel.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13723349/selenium-grid-maxsessions-vs-maxinstances).